# Haskell equivalent of assert(0)

Tags: haskell, assert

I'm trying to figure out what is the best practice to write the Haskell equivalent of `assert(0)`. I know that type safety dictates that an integer must be returned from `scanList`, however I wonder if there's a better way than what I wrote. Is there any way to avoid the arbitrary number `923` that is just stuck there?

```
module Main (main) where

import Control.Exception (assert)

l = [
    Left "1",
    Left "1",
    Right 1,
    Right 1,
    Left "9"]

scanList :: [ Either String Int ] -> Int
scanList [    ] = 0
scanList (x:xs) = case x of
    Right i -> i + scanList xs
    Left  s ->
        if read s < 8
        then read s + scanList xs
        else assert False $ 923

main = do
    print $ scanList l
```

Comment: I suggest using assertions only for invariants in your code (where a failure means a bug), they help document invariants and compliment your tests. `assert` calls have no overhead since they are removed when compiling with optimizations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation of `assert`:

> If the first argument evaluates to True, then the result is the second argument. Otherwise an AssertionFailed exception is raised, containing a String with the source file and line number of the call to assert.

So instead of giving `False` as first argument you could actually check your `if` condition there:

```
scanList (x:xs) = case x of
    Right i -> i + scanList xs
    Left  s ->
        assert (read s < 8) (read s + scanList xs)
```

Answer (score 4):

The more idiomatic Haskell design would be to keep pure functions **total**. When using `assert`, you're throwing an exception, which makes the function **partial**. This means that you can no longer trust the type of the function. It claims to have the type `[Either String Int] -> Int`, but will fail with an exception at run-time under various conditions.

A total function would either stay within the `Either` monad, or could, alternatively, translate to `Maybe`:

```
import Text.Read

scanList :: (Num a, Read a, Ord a) => [Either String a] -> Maybe a
scanList [] = Just 0
scanList (x:xs) =
  case x of
    Right i -> fmap (+ i) $ scanList xs
    Left s -> 
      case readMaybe s of
        Just i -> if i < 8 then fmap (+ i) $ scanList xs else Nothing
        Nothing -> Nothing
```

You could simplify the code quite a bit, but I chose to keep it structurally as close to the OP as possible.

With a type like `[Either String a] -> Maybe a`, any caller knows that they have to handle both `Just` and `Nothing` cases, without having to resort to reading the code or documentation of the function in question.

Comment: I see. So is there any reasonable scenario where one *should* use assertions in Haskell? Like you said, given any function returning a type `T` I can always `Maybe` it and avoid assertions altogether, right? Why did the Haskell guys enable it?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom There's a couple of reasons that exceptions are still part of Haskell. One of them is that Haskell is an old language, and that certain language features are still around for historical or backwards compatibility reasons. Another reason is that you could argue that exceptions are still appropriate in the context of `IO`, where functions are already impure.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom, assertions are for checking that *your code* is correct. In many cases, you can indeed avoid them by carefully ensuring that your invariants are enforced structurally or through the type system. But sometimes you can't, or can't easily, do so. Suppose you have a weight-balanced tree. You may add an assertion to your rebalancing operation(s) to verify that each resulting node is actually balanced appropriately.